# handle ajax response to display button in datatables

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable

i have my datatable that looks like this

```
<table id="list" class="display"  width="100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and i have a js function that call data using ajax to that table, here is the js function below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
          url :"list.php",
          type: "GET",
          error: function(){
            $("#post_list_processing").css("display","none");
          }
        },
        "columns": [
              { "data": "title" },
              { "data": "description" }
          ]
  });
});
```

currently this ajax response is returning data with the product id in json format like the below example

> data:[{id: "12", title: "product1", description: "test",…},…] 0:{id:
>   "12", title: "product1", description: "test",…}

what i am trying to do is to show under delete column a link with the delete link that i should pass the product id via the delete url, but i can't seem to wrap my head around how to handle the response id and display a button for the delete function in the datable, can you please help me out ? thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

list.php

```
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    $columns = array(
        0 => 'title',
        1 => 'description'
    );

    $where_condition = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {
        $where_condition .= " WHERE ";
        $where_condition .= " ( title LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $where_condition .= " OR description LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }

    $sql_query = " SELECT * FROM products ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql_query;
    $sqlRec .= $sql_query;

    if(isset($where_condition) && $where_condition != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where_condition;
        $sqlRec .= $where_condition;
    }

    $sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";


    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $queryTot = $db->query($sqlTot);

        $totalRecords = $queryTot->rowCount();

        $queryRecords = $db->query($sqlRec);

        while( $row = $queryRecords->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 
        $data[] = $row;
        }   

        $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data"            => $data
        );

        $db = null;
        if(empty($json_data)) {
            $response->getBody()->write($error);
        } else {
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($json_data));
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $response->getBody()->write($errormsg);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to modify ajax response in list.php?

Comment: yes @AliSheikhpour

Comment: Ok! add a new field to json response like this: `deleteLink:"<a href='deletepage.php?id=idToDelete'>delete</a>"` and show the deleteLink as a new column in columns list

Comment: @AliSheikhpour added list.php to my question, how do i access idToDelete then ? can u please post an answer to help me out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you want something like that

[About generating columns](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hnb0j6qy/4/)

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": [

      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 1
      },

      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "columns": [{
      "data": "title"
    },
                {
                  "data": "description"
                },
                {
                  "data": function(item) {
                    return '<a href="/delete/' + item.id + '">Delete</a>';
                  }
                }
               ]
  });

  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    alert(data[0] + "'s salary is: " + data[5]);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you that worked, but i have a question lets say for example i want to capitalizeFirstLetter of title in response or generate multiple links under the same color (Delete, edit..) how can i do that ?

Comment: Same thing - you can modify any column you want by function. Just return the value you need to display (capitalized string or html - whatever)

Comment: can you show me how pls ? and how to generate multiple links under the same color (Delete, edit..)

Answer (score 0):

You can both generate the Delete Link on list.php or when processing ajax response.

In client-side method you will need using `"dataSrc`" method to modify ajax response before using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
          "url" :"list.php",
          "type": "GET",
          "error": function(){$("#post_list_processing").css("display","none");},
          "dataSrc": function (json) {
              var return_data = new Array();
              for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){
                return_data.push({
                  'title': json[i].title,
                  'description' : json[i].description,
                  'deleteLink' : '<a href="delete.php?id' + json[i].id +'">delete</a>"
                })
              }
              return return_data;
            }
          },
        "columns": [
              { "data": "title" },
              { "data": "description" },
              { "data": "deleteLink" }
          ]
  });
});
```

In server-side method you can generate HTML of delete link using PHP concatenation (+) on ID and html tags and insert the delete link as once as a new element of JSON response. So you will have no need to **dataSrc** on ajax to modify *respons data*.

Comment: thank you Ali, I added this to the client side but now the page is not loading any data